# convert arrayList multimap to json string?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following code:

```
public static void postHttpStream(ArrayListMultimap<String, String> fcmbuildProperties){
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(fcmbuildProperties);
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(fcmbuildProperties);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
}
```

where fcmbuildProperties is an ArrayListMultimap. I try to convert that to JSON here: `String jsonString = gson.toJson(fcmbuildProperties);`  But this returns an empty array.  What do I need to do instead?

This is the input that fcmbuildProperties contain : `{build.name=[test_project], build.timestamp=[1425600727488], build.number=[121]}`

I need to convert this to Json. with key/values.

Comment: Give us a full example with actual input and output and the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ArrayListMultimap#asMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#asMap%28%29)

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(fcmbuildProperties.asMap());
```

Gson considers `ArrayListMultimap` as a `Map` and ignores its internal state which actually manages the multimap. `asMap` returns a corresponding `Map` instance which you can serialize as expected.